# What is causing this "the cell or chart you are trying to change is protected" in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I've got a simple VBA sub that unlocks all sheets in the workbook, calls Application.RefreshAll, and re-locks. On the *very last line* (the Application.DisplayAlerts = True) I get this popup warning me that the cell is protected.

If I step through the sub in the debugger, I do not get the warning. It's only if I let it just run normally.

I have put break points in the code, including at the call to LockAllSheets. It runs fine throughout and only shows the popup when Application.DisplayAlerts is set back to True. I have also disabled the initial setting of DisplayAlerts to False, thinking that it might just be "saving" an alert that it wanted to previously display, but that didn't make a difference.

I've set a watch for Err.number, and it is always zero.

I have also done a Range("A1").Select to see if that did anything, and it did not.

The only thing I've found that makes a difference is commenting out the call to LockAllSheets, which of course is something I don't want to do anyway.

```
Private Sub btnUpdateAll_Click()
    On Error Resume Next
    Me.Range("A1:A4").Value = ""

    Me.Range("A1:A4").Font.Color = vbBlue
    Me.Range("A1") = "Now refreshing all data...please wait"
    Me.Range("A2") = "You can monitor progress in the Queries panel on the right."
    Application.CommandBars("Queries and Connections").Visible = True
    Application.StatusBar = "Refreshing tables...this may take a minute"
    
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      
    Call UnlockAllSheets
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Me.Range("A1:A4").Font.Color = vbRed
        Me.Range("A1").Value = "The required Oracle driver isn't installed. Create an IT ticket to install it. "
        Err.Clear
    Else
        Me.Range("A1") = "Workbook last refreshed on " & Now
        Me.Range("A2") = "The data warehouse updates nightly."
    End If
    
    On Error GoTo err_handler
    Application.CommandBars("Queries and Connections").Visible = False
    Application.StatusBar = False

    Call LockAllSheets
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Exit Sub
err_handler:
    MsgBox "An error has occurred: " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    Stop
End Sub
```

```
Sub LockAllSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If Not ws.ProtectContents Then
            ws.Protect Password:=sPassword, userinterfaceonly:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub UnlockAllSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        ws.Unprotect sPassword
    Next
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If you take out all the `Application.DisplayAlerts` assignments, you might on debug get the error where it happens.

Comment: @harrymc - I already tried that. :-/
I also rewrote the sub to specify each table I wanted to refresh, with calls like
Worksheets("Dashboard").ListObjects(1).TableObject.Refresh
but no change.

Comment: Here's another oddity - if I download the file to my computer the error goes away. If I open it from Teams I get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Aha! Figured it out. I noticed that when the warning about locked sheets pops up, Excel said "Running background query" on the status bar. One of the queries - the one that uses PowerQuery to filter a table and create a filtered table on a different tab - was still running after VBA locked the sheets. Unchecking its box to enable refresh in the background fixed things.

edit: though the lock uses userinterfaceonly=true, so I'm not sure why Excel would still take issue with it.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a guess here, try

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
  
'Your code ...

Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: Good idea, thanks...but doesn't make a difference.